# Messages put in same ConversationID when they're not in reply - Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

It seems that on some messages we've received into our system, they have the same ConversationID (quite likely because they have the same subject) but are not necessarily in reply to the other messages with the same ConversationID.

Given that we use the ConversationID to thread messages in our system and this is therefore tying together messages that are not related, is it possible to have some of the internet message headers added to the Message object in Graph? Particularly useful would be the In-Reply-To and References headers, so that we can manually check where to place messages based on the previous message's InternetMessageID?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the subject will result in a new conversation, but not necessarily that a matching subject will end up in same conversation. Subject is just one out of many other properties we check including in-reply-to, references, conversation id, conversation index, topic and some other properties, resulting in many possible patterns depending on the available info we have in the incoming message and existing items we can match to in the mailbox.

Using the conversation id is the right property to group the messages.  Providing internet message headers is in our backlog, but we don’t have a date yet to share for delivering this feature.